# How to access the derived class properties from base class instance using generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance

I am trying to access all the properties of my derived class through base class reference variable.

Classes

```
        public class vehicle
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
        }

        public class Car : vehicle
        {
            public string type  { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the main in Main class

```
public static void saveCar<T>(T vehicle) where T : vehicle
        {
            //TODO : here I need to access all the propertie values but I dunno how access only derived class values             


        }
```

I am trying to do this way

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Car cr = new Car
            {
                ID = 1,
                type = "car",
                Name = "Maruthi"
            };
            saveCar<Car>(cr);            


        }
```

Comment: I think your design is wrong.  This should be a virtual method on `Vehicle` and overridden in each.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really ask for T and know your real properties. 
I think you should change your design to something like this:

```
    public abstract class Vehicle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual void SaveCar()
        {
            // save Id
        }
    }

    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public string Type  { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override void SaveCar()
        {
            base.SaveCar();
            // Save type & name
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have saveCar as a generic method? If the saveCar method is a virtual method on Vehicle you can override and have the required extended save functionality in each derived type.
However if you require an external method to handle actions such as save and have Vehicle and its derived classes as simple data representations, you will need to inspect the object and act accordingly. Some like:

```
    public static void saveCar(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        if (vehicle != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(vehicle.ID);
            if (vehicle is Car)
            {
                var car = vehicle as Car;
                Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But I dunno it would be of what type. I want to make it very generic. Say I  will create one class bike inheriting from vehicle. In this case my saveCar method should be able to access bike properties as well.

Comment: The point being - if the saveCar (or saveVehicle which is more indicative of the use) only handles saving of types deriving from the Vehicle base class you shouldn't need to have a generic method in the first place.  You're already forcing T to be of type vehicle, so you know it will be a vehicle or a derived version thereof.  To be able to access properties of a Car instance you have to know that it is a Car instance you're dealing with.